# why @autowired doos not instanciate my field?

Tags: spring, swing, autowired

I'm using Spring boot annotation style, and I don't understand after several searches, why the annotated field returns null.

Please below my java code:

```
package app.ui;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
  private JMenu     fileMenu;
  private JMenuBar  menuBar;
  private JMenuItem openMenuItem;

  @Autowired
  MyDialog myDialog;

  @Autowired
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


  public MyFrame() {
    initComponents();
    setVisible(true);
  }


  private void initComponents() {
    jdbcTemplate.toString();
    this.setTitle("Vue de ma fenêtre");
    this.setSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new JMenu();
    openMenuItem = new JMenuItem();
    fileMenu.setText("File");
    openMenuItem.setText("Inscription");
    openMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        myDialog.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
    fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    //
    final JButton cmd1 = new JButton("Créer Table");
    getContentPane().add(cmd1);
    cmd1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE customers IF EXISTS");
        jdbcTemplate.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE customer(id bigint(11), nom VARCHAR(55), prenom VARCHAR(55), dnaiss date)");
        cmd1.setEnabled(false);
      }
    });

    //
```

in this sample, `jdbcTemplate.toString()` returns  null, and I can't understand why, because it works below in the action Performed method

Thank you for Help.

Comment: there is none jdbctemplates configured in your container

Comment: could you post your configuration?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I have no xml configuration. what can i post to to enlighten you. how to do to configure jdbctemplates in my container ?

Comment: Then i guess you have a Java Config with Annotations, could you show us?

Comment: How are you getting an instance of `MyFrame`? Do you get it from Spring or are you doing `new MyFrame()` somewhere? If you do the latter, then the `MyFrame` object is not a Spring managed bean and no autowiring will be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the way Java initializes class , first constructor got executed later class variables got initialized . untill and unless variables are part of static block .same logic is followed by spring as well .

in your example jdbcTemplate is a class variable,  jdbcTemplate.toString(); is called via default constructor , while actionperformed is called on instance of MyFrame .

to know more about class initialization please check below link

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075796/java-platform/java-101--class-and-object-initialization.html?nsdr=true

Comment: Thank you Bhupi, you got it !